# S8050 datasheet typo?

Tags: transistors, datasheet

I have some S8050 transistors and was looking for the stats of them in the datasheet. I found some strange values for the Ib/Ic relation:

[image: S8050 datasheet excerpt]

Shouldn't the unit on the y-axis be A instead of mA? The datasheet of all S8050 subtypes have A on this axis. Ib 1.5 mA = Ic 0.25 mA would be a DC current gain of 0.167, as far as I understood.

Comment: Yeah, that does look funny. Can you post a link to the data sheet?

Comment: I found two datasheets with this chart, one is from UNISONIC TECHNOLOGIES CO., LTD. (http://media.nkcelectronics.com/datasheet/s8050.pdf), the other one from Samsung (https://alltransistors.com/pdfview.php?doc=ss8050.pdf&dire=_samsung). And here is another one from LGE using uA and mA instead of mA and A (but nevertheless with the proper relation of 100) https://alltransistors.com/pdfview.php?doc=s8050_to-92.pdf&dire=_lge. All quite confusing for an electronic beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an obvious typo.  If you check [Mouser - Fairchild SS8050](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/SS8050-117753.pdf), \$I_C\$ is in Amps.

[image: Static Characteristics]

Comment: I will flag this as the answer, as a current gain of < 1 does not make sense with a transistor. The 1:100 ratio or bigger seems to be correct.

Comment: Lots of small errors occur in datasheets, mainly because they are created by graphic artists and technical writers and they can propagate as parts are sourced by different companies.

Comment: Ok, never fully trust a datasheet is my lesson for today. That somehow reminds me of Lockheed Martin's metric confusion that shredded a 125 million dollar probe on mars back in '99.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far.  I'd say >99.9% of datasheets are accurate.  Does the info make sense within the operation of the device?  Typically, answered by common sense.  At the end of the day, you are responsible for the decisions you make or don't make.